# How to get item from a list that position in a certain place

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

Please consider this scenario:

For some math calculations I should find a number in specific place in a **sorted** list. For example consider this list:

```
1 - 2 - 3 - ... 17 - 18 - 19 - 20
```

I should to find number placed in **25%** of count (**count / 4**). In above series I should get 5. It is worth noting that we haven't round count number but it's not a problem.

Now consider this table:

```
Type            Number
----------------------
  1               10
  1               11
  1               12
  1               13
  2               22
  2               23
  2               24
  2               25
  2               26
  2               27
  2               28
  3               39
  3               38
  3               37
  3               36
  3               35
  3               34
  3               33
  3               32
  4               41
  4               43
  4               42
  4               44
  4               45
  4               47
  4               46
  4               48
  4               49
  4               50
  4               51
```

> Another point is I'm sure that in every `Type` I have at least 1000
> numbers, so above data in just for example.

according to above data I want to get this result:

```
Type            Number
----------------------
  1               11
  2               23
  3               33
  4               43
```

One way to achieve this result is to loop throw distinct `Type` and get list of number and then sort it and then calculate count of that list and divide it by 4, then round the result and get specific `Number` with the index has been gotten.

But the problem with this approach is it needs many connection to database (1 for each `Type`). Is there any better solution to get desired result with 1 connection and 1 query execution. thanks

Comment: I am not able to relate expected output with calculation (count/4) , need more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting puzzle. In Sql Server you could use something like the following query;

```sql
select a.*
from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by type order by number) as row_number
    from table_name
) a
join (
    select type, count(*) as count
    from table_name
    group by type
) b on a.type = b.type
where a.row_number = b.count/4
```

(With whatever rounding you want for when `count%4 != 0`)

But I can't think how you would build that as a linq expression.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var percent = 0.25;
 var val = res.GroupBy(x => x.type)
              .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.OrderBy(y=>y).ToList());
 var valuesTobeTaken = val.Select(x => new 
                              { 
                                 x.Key, 
                                 index = ((int)Math.Round(x.Value.Count * percent))-1 
                               });
```

> Edge cases are not handled and the code is not too much optimized. You can work on that i guess

```
        foreach (var rec in valuesTobeTaken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(val[rec.Key][rec.index]);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but it works on lists. We haven't `ToDictionary` in `Linq` to databases

Comment: Another problem is if we write above code consistently with database, again for each type it goes to database, because of: `x.Value.Count` and `val[rec.Key][rec.index]`

Comment: Why do you want to transfer the calculation logic to db because given only two columns, even if the Data size is huge, EF should be fine. res should be your context.TableName, and if you replace res.GroupBy.xxxxx with  context.TableName.GroupBy...... at .ToDictionary(), DB connection is over.  I agree we can move the logic to db, let me think over it. I will post a solution